# How can I use the AND statement to compare two tables?

Tags: php, sql, select

I'm trying to write a statement that will check 2 tables and compare the 2 and only show the users who are not on table2. For example: 
**table1** has user1, user2, user3, and user4 AND 
**table2** has user1, user3, and user4 then it would only show user2 in the list.

I was able to write something as basic as to only show member_id='1' but I don't how to make it work the way I would like. I'm hoping you understand my question. I'll include the short code that deals with this issue...

```
$sql->db_Select(DB_TABLE_ROSTER_MEMBERS, "*", "member_id='1' AND
                               (member_status like 'Team Member%'
                                OR member_status like 'Squad Leader%'
                                OR member_status like 'Recruiter%'
                                OR member_status like 'New Recruit%'$customArgs)
                               ORDER BY member_application_date DESC");
```

the syntax for this can be located here- http://wiki.e107.org/index.php?title=Db#db_Select.28.29
I'm guessing I just need to make another select DB and just have it included in the above so it would be something like

```
member_id != $member_id
```

where $member_id would be something like $member_id = $row['member_id'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a LEFT JOIN and check where table2.member_id IS NULL.

Comment: ahhh not more join things lol. i still hvnt been able to fully understand that. with help from the members here i was able to finally get a JOIN to work for another function on the same code but that was with some help.

Comment: Read a tutorial and try it yourself. It is no magic. http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

Comment: i used the inner join before. i could possibly adapt that to work. idk much about JOIN but would inner join do the same thing?
(i tried to include the inner join code but this text thing is F'ed up. couldnt get it to show right)

Comment: No, an INNER JOIN is not the same. An INNER JOIN forces both tables to have the same value in the row where you join them. So you can not use it here. Read the tutrial and try a simple example yourself. You will see how it works.

Comment: il try but the only problem i see is getting it converted into e107 syntax. but let me give it a shot and see what happens..

Comment: mh... can't help you there. I have no idea about e107.

Comment: ya... this makes little to no sense to me. i couldn't even begin to get it to work either as php or sql. it has no similarities to the code that im currently working with. If i was to give you details would you be able to create a sql command or whatever its called and then i could find my own way of converting it to the correct syntax? A MySQL Query i guess is wat its called.

Comment: you can use the **NOT IN** clause in your query like NOT IN (select statement from Table2) inside your where clause

Comment: so something like 

    NOT IN (jbclan_roster_team_members, member_id)

    or simply NOT IN (table2, Field)

Answer (score 0):

First, `AND` is an operator ;)

Second, there are many relational operators that imply logical AND e.g. intersect, join, product (SQL `CROSS JOIN`), restriction (SQL `WHERE`, extension (SQL `AS` clause) and matching/difference (SQL `MATCH` or `EXISTS` or `IN`).

Third, from your first sentence I rather think you are looking for relational operators that imply logical NOT i.e. non-existential qualification. Again, there are many options e.g. minus (SQL `EXCEPT`), not matching/semi-difference (SQL `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` but bizarrely not `NOT MATCH`!); personally, I find `OUTER JOIN` testing for nulls to be the most odd (not to mention not relational)!

Fourth, your relational/SQL product of choice will likely not support and/or equally optimize all the different options from a given relational algebra or SQL Standard.

My personal choice for [semi-difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29) is `NOT EXISTS`: the name clearly implies non-existential qualification, the predicates are located close together in SQL code, is widely supported and usually well optimized:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM table2
                    WHERE table2.member_id = table1.member_id  -- predicates close together
                  );
```